# How to run qmake from the static Qt

Tags: c++, qt, installation

For making a very simple Qt app "installable" on other systems, I'm using *Qt Installer Framework* following [this link](http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-getting-started.html).
In bottom, in *Setting up Qt Installer Framework*, number 1 orders to have *Qt Installer Framework source code*. I downloaded it [from here](https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt-installer-framework/2.0.1/). (*qt-installer-framework-opensource-2.0.1-src.zip*)

Now I don't understand the next instruction there :(
It says:
*2- Build the tools by running the "qmake" from the static Qt, followed by "make" or "nmake".*

My question is, first what does it mean?
And from what path?
I don't know how to do it:(

Answer (score 0):

qmake comes with the qt-framework and is a make file generator. (an alternative to cmake).
You call qmake on a `.pro` file from your project. This `.pro` file have to contain your source code files project dependencies and more.

Consider that you have a project folder with your source code and the .pro file. Then you call the `qmake` command in this folder. qmake is an program itself, which you can find in the bin folder of your qt-installation. If qmake is in your path variable, you go to the terminal, navigate to the specific folder and just write:

```
qmake
```

After that qmake will create a makefile. Then you could call `make`and your program will be build.

I hope my answer helps you. You can learn more about qmake on the website of [Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-manual.html). Here is also a very good qmake tutorial: [klick](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-tutorial.html)

edit:

how to call make on windows:
download and install cygwin from

http://www.cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe - 32 bit installer or

http://www.cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe - 64 bit installer.

then start the Cygwin terminal (Cygwin.bat) and navigate to your folder and call

```
make
```

and that will build your qt-installer!

Comment: Thanks but I didn't say how to build my program! It's built and run. I want to create an installabe version of it.

Comment: What is your question? You downloaded the installer framework and didn't understand the next step, right? The answer: After the download go to the terminal, navigate to the downloaded files and call: qmake. After that call make.

Comment: I went to the downloaded folder and ran *qmake -project*. some files were added to the folder. Then none of *make -project* or *nmake -project* is **recognized as an internal or external command**.

Comment: Yes, Windows 7 x64

Comment: Please have a look to number 2. It says: "from the static Qt". Where is *static Qt*?

Comment: I think  static Qt means just your normal qt installation. If you work on windows, it is clear that your system don't find make. You need `nmake`. Nmake comes with Visual Studio. Explaining how to use it, is maybe an other good question. I very hope this helps you a little bit and never give up :)

Comment: Thank you for your hope. (+1)

Comment: I modified the answer with how to use make on windows. I think this should help you. If yes, you could accept the answer ;-)